# Set limit to string in regular expression with white spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, whitespace

I have this regular expression

```
/^([a-zA-Z01-9]+ ?){0,20}$/
```

I have a set of rules

- The string line can't start with a white space.
- The string cannot be longer than 20 characters **including the white spaces**.
- The string cannot have two white spaces consecutively.
- The string can ends with a white space.

The only problem that I have is to set the length of the string including the white space to 20 as maximum.

Comment: Why just don't you test it with JavaScript? `str.length <= 20`...

Comment: Do you have to do everything with a single regex? Honestly, if this is some kind of validation, I'd just trim the initial white space and collapse the remaining ones then check for the `string.length`.

Comment: Because I'm using this for a masked textbox jQuery plugin, so the text will be evaluated as every keypress and limit to write more than 20 characters.

Comment: Setting the `maxlength` property wouldn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this: `^(?=[a-zA-Z\d\s]{0,20}$)([a-zA-Z01-9]+ ?)*$`